# Trying to force surjectivity by adding some assumptions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A, B $ and $C$ are non empty sets. Denote by $A^B$ as the collection of all functions from $B $ into $A$ and similarly for $A^C$. Let $f : C \rightarrow B$ be a function, and define $\varphi : A^B \rightarrow A^C $, $\varphi(g) := g \circ f , \, \forall g \in A^B $.  I have shown already that this mapping is well defined.

Now suppose that $\varphi$ is injective, that is, given two mappings, $g_1 , g_2 : B \rightarrow A$ such that $\varphi(g_1) = \varphi(g_2)$ , we must have $g_1 = g_2$.

Under this condition on $\varphi$ alone  it is not necessarily true that $f$ is surjective.
My question is, Are there other conditions I can place on $\varphi$,  that would gaurantee $f$ being surjective?
I have already tried proving $f$  surjective under the extra assumption that $\varphi$ is, but to no avail. Any tips in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a very well-known result in topos theory (which is a sort of set theory approached from the perspective of category theory).

We are given $f : C \to B$ and asked under what conditions we can prove that $f$ is surjective.

The trick here is to define, for all $A$, a map $\phi_A : A^B \to A^C$ by $\phi(g) = g \circ f$. Then $f$ is surjective if and only if for all $A$, $\phi_A$ is injective.

The property that $\phi_A$ is injective for all $A$ is commonly phrased by category theorists as "$f$ is an epimorphism". So the theorem is that epimorphisms and surjections are exactly the same (in the category of sets).

Proof:

Clearly, if $f$ is surjective, then $\phi_A$ will be injective for all $A$. For if we have $\phi_A(g) = \phi_A(h)$, then $g \circ f = h \circ f$. Now given an arbitrary $b \in B$, take some $c \in C$ such that $f(c) = b$. Then $g(b) = g(f(c)) = h(f(c)) = h(b)$. Thus, we see that $g = h$ by function extensionality. Therefore, we see that $\phi_A$ is indeed injective.

Conversely, suppose that $\phi_A$ is injective for all $A$. Then in particular, $\phi_\Omega$ is injective for a special set $\Omega = P(1)$, where $1$ is a fixed 1-element set $1 = \{*\}$.

Define $g, h : B \to \Omega$ by $g(b) = 1$ and $h(b) = \{x \in 1 \mid \exists c \in C (b = f(c))\}$. Note that $h(b) = 1$ if and only if $\exists c \in C (b = f(c))$.

We now demonstrate that $g \circ f = h \circ f$. For consider some $c \in C$. Then clearly $g(f(c)) = 1$. And note that clearly, $\exists c' \in C (f(c) = f(c'))$. So therefore, $h(f(c)) = 1$ as well. Therefore, $g \circ f = h \circ f$.

Then $\phi_\Omega(g) = \phi_\Omega(h)$. Since $\phi_\Omega$ is injective, $g = h$.

Consider an arbitrary $b \in B$. Then $h(b) = g(b) = 1$. Therefore, there exists $c \in C$ such that $b = f(c)$.

Therefore, $f$ is surjective.